# How to update database value using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to change a value in Database using Google cloud functions.

Here is the value I want to change:

[image: Here is the value I want to change] 
And here is my code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 100 minutes")
    .onRun((context) => {
      functions.database.ref("/test1/yeniYemlemeSaati")
          .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
            snapshot.ref.parent.child("yeniYemlemeSaati").set("12:12");
          });
    });
```

I followed this doc. [Extend Realtime Database with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions) But I couldn't get out of it and I am getting the following error. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TArEe.png) 
Since I had my first experience with Cloud Functions and I didn't develop JavaScript, I couldn't. I hope you help.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js script, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. To set the value every 100 minutes, you need:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 100 minutes")
.onRun((context) => {
    admin.database().ref("test1/yeniYemlemeSaati").set("12:12");
});
```

If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js script, possibly with the [Emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.